# How make aws-curl exlude fields from elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to send a request to aws elasticsearch with [aws-es-curl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-es-curl):

```
aws-es-curl https://myhost.es.amazonaws.com/my-index/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size": "100","index":"my-index", "_source": {"excludes": ["attachment.*","data"], "includes": "owner"}}'
```

But this returns me all fields. Also I `size` parameter is also not recognized :( Why this happens? How pass those parameters to es?

ES version is `5.3`

Source variants are [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/search-request-source-filtering.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pipe the content of your query into the curl command:

```
echo '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size": "100", "_source": {"excludes": ["attachment.*","data"], "includes": "owner"}}' | aws-es-curl -X POST https://myhost.es.amazonaws.com/my-index/_search
```